# Call the name of a data frame rather than its content (Pandas)

Tags: python, string, list, pandas

I have a list of dataframes but when I call the content of the list it returns the content of the called dataframe.

> > > List = [df1, df2, df3, ..., dfn]
> > >
> > > List[1]

will give,
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4753 entries, etc

but I want it to give

> > > str(List[1])???

'df2'

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrame doesn't know the name of the variable you've assigned to it.

Depending on how you're printing the object, either the `__str__` or `__repr__` method will get called to get a description of the object.  If you want to get back 'df2', you could put them into a dictionary to map the name back to the object.

If you want to be very sneaky, you could patch the object's `__str__` or `__repr__` methods to return what you want.  This is probably a very bad idea, though.

Comment: Thanks dmcauslan,  Strange, I would have thought there would be an easy way of calling only the name of the df ('df2') without the need of getting them in a dictionary!!!